# Como parar de ler do sys.stdin em Python 3 após atingir um número delimitado de linhas?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando receber comando do sys.stdin até que atinja um limite `n` de linhas, e depois termine a execução automaticamente.

O meu código está como segue:

```
import sys

A = [] 
n = int(input("number of nodes: "))
for line in sys.stdin:
    if len(line.split()) == 2:
        A.append(line.split())    
    else:
        print("Requires two integers, ie: 1 2. You typed:", line)
print(A)
```

Esse código vai pedir um valor inicial, que vai ser atribuído a `n`. Depois disso vai ficar adicionando pares de número a `lista A`. Eu queria que parasse de pedir comando após a `lista` conter dimensão igual a `n`

Exemplo de input seria:

```
> 2

> 1 2

> 2 3
```

e o output seria:

`[['1','2'], ['2','3']]`

Mas do jeito que está agora ele fica adicionando à lista de maneira indeterminada, até que o usuário de o sinal que terminou de digitar. Como faço para que seja automático o fim da execução uma vez que a `len(A) == n`?

Comment: se eu ponho no final do código, após o `else` mas antes do `print(A)`, um `if len(A) == n: break`, funciona como eu gostaria, mas acredito que exista um jeito mais apropriado de atingir isso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O jeito que você descreveu [nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/450617/como-parar-de-ler-do-sys-stdin-em-python-3-ap%C3%B3s-atingir-um-n%C3%BAmero-delimitado-de/450628#comment862842_450617) é uma alternativa válida sim (a diferença é que eu só preciso testar o tamanho da lista se algum elemento for inserido - ou seja, dentro do `if`, pois não tem porque testar no `else`, nem fora do `if`, já que nesses casos a lista não foi modificada):

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    v = line.split()
    if len(v) == 2:
        A.append(v)
        if len(A) == n:
            break
    else:
        print("Requires two integers, ie: 1 2. You typed:", line)
```

Também alterei o código para fazer o `split` uma vez só.

---

Se bem que [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) também lê do [`stdin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin), então outra alternativa é usar um *loop* infinito e ir lendo até que a lista tenha o tamanho desejado:

```
while True:
    v = input().split()
    if len(v) == 2:
        A.append(v)    
        if len(A) == n:
            break
    else:
        print("Requires two integers, ie: 1 2. You typed:", v)
```

Se a ideia é só parar quando a lista tiver `n` elementos, e um novo elemento só é adicionado em determinadas condições (ou seja, nem todas as linhas serão inseridas na lista), então não tem jeito: tem que ir lendo indefinidamente, e a cada vez que a lista for modificada, tem que testar se ela já possui o tamanho desejado para saber se o *loop* deve ser interrompido.

Comment: Bem mais compreensível a leitura do seu código. Muito obrigado pelas informações, eu não sabia que o input() pode funcionar como o sys.stdin